# Algorithm without dynamic programming,less efficient solution

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, dynamic-programming

There is a problem asked in contest. I already solved this problem with dynamic programming and its complexity `O(n^2)`. But i am looking for solution with less efficient way. What will be the complexity of this less efficient way. Thanks for the helps.

Comment: I guess you mean "more efficient way"? Otherwise, its easy to make the algorithm arbitrarily inefficient.

Comment: i mean less efficent way. I would like to compare their complexity.For instance i am looking for a O(n^3) solution

Comment: @mustad: `O(n^2)` is a subset of `O(n^3)`, so an `O(n^2)` solution is also an `O(n^3)` solution.

Comment: @amit assume `Theta(n^3)`; it's still trivial to make an algorithm arbitrarily slow.

Comment: By the way, did you know you can sort arrays in `Th((3/2)^n)`?

Comment: I also must be missing something in the problem. Won't finding the solution by going up the tree from each node to the root will be `O(n*h)` which is also `O(n^2)`, since `h < n` ?

Comment: @amit yes it is O(n^2) but can anybody tell how can i solve this problem for instance in O(n^3). I want it less efficient.

Comment: Implement an O(n^2) solution, but do it n times before returning the result.

Answer (score 2):

There is a general way to make any dynamic programming solution less efficient. The essence of dynamic programming is to store solutions to sub-problems for reuse.

To make it less efficient in a somewhat reasonable way, get rid of the sub-problem result storage. Instead, recalculate each sub-problem solution whenever you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Using inefficient data structure with same algorithm can help to have `O(n^3)`. Storing towns in a linked list instead of an array will make algorithm one order less efficient.

To make it even less efficient, it is easier to change algorithm. For example checking of all harbinger changing combinations and using minimal, which is exponential in time.